# How Can I store a custom view into the Bitmap object

Tags: android, bitmap

How Can I store a custom view into the  `Bitmap` object? For example using following code we can store the `imageView` object into the `bitmap` object.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

But if I create  a custom view using the following code, How Can I store the custom view into the `Bitmap` object?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Custom custom;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//How Can I store the `custom` object into the `Bitmap` object? Can I do this? 

    }}

class Custom extends View{
    Paint paint;

    Custom(Context context){
super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//Some operations

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to do this. you have to create a Bitmap and a Canvas and call view.draw(canvas);

here is the code:

`public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getLayoutParams().width,v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}`